# ValueError: Scorer initialization failed with error code 1

Tags: tensorflow, initialization, valueerror, mozilla-deepspeech

I am new to tensorflow. I am studying the project deepspeechhttps://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech, but when I run evauate.py, I get the error:

> ValueError: Scorer initialization failed with error code 1

the details as follows. Can anybody can help me resolve this issue, thanks!

Stack information：

```
  File "/home/zhangp/Desktop/sr/DeepSpeech-master/evaluate.py", line 49, in evaluate
    FLAGS.scorer_path, Config.alphabet)

  File "/home/zhangp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ds_ctcdecoder/__init__.py", line 41, in __init__
    raise ValueError('Scorer initialization failed with error code {}'.format(err))

ValueError: Scorer initialization failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Im not the most python / deepspeech expert out there but from their [mozilla discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/valueerror-scorer-initialization-failed-with-error-code-1/54939) and after facing the same issue. This is whats happening and its fix:

"It means the scorer hasn’t been installed You need to install git-lfs and do git lfs pull to download it.".

On MacOS git-lfs is installed via brew or apt-get install on linux, and then run "git lfs pull".